# How can I assign and use function pointers of 2 different classes between among them?

Tags: c++, class, stack, protocols, function-pointers

I'm developing a protocol stack and I have wrote a different levels with classes they have functions and function pointers for connect different levels among them.

I have problems to manage and assign function pointers. The situation is similar to the following (simplified):

File baseA.h:

```
class baseA
{
    public:
        virtual void fnc1(void)=0;
    void (B::*fnc2)(void)=NULL;
};
```

File A.h:

```
class A:baseA
{
    public:
        void task(void);

        void fnc1(void);
        void (B::*fnc2)(void)=NULL;
};
```

File A.cpp:

```
void A::task()
{
    if(this->fnc2!=NULL)
        this->fnc2();
}

void A::fnc1(void)
{
    //Do something
}
```

File B.h:

```
class B
{
    public:
        void task(void);

        void fnc1(void);
        void (baseA::*fnc2)(void);
};
```

File B.cpp:

```
void B::task(void)
{
    if(this->fnc2!=NULL)
        this->fnc2();
}

void B::fnc1(void)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Main function:

```
main(void)
{
    A instA;
    B instB;

    instA.fnc2 = instB.fnc1;
    instB.fnc2 = instA.fnc1;

    while(1)
    {
        instA.task();
        instB.task();
    }
}
```

I have two problems:

1. in the function main, when I assign the function pointers , the compiler return me the errors "`cannot convert 'B::fnc1' from type 'void (B::)()' to type 'void (*)()'`" (for `instA.fnc2 = instB.fnc1;`) and "`cannot convert 'A::fnc1' from type 'void (A::)()' to type 'void (*)()'`" (for `instB.fnc2 = instA.fnc1;`).
2. when I use the function pointers, inside the `task` functions, the compiler return me the error "`must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((A*)this)->A::fnc2 (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((A*)this)->A::fnc2) (...)'`". I have tried to use `(this->*fnc2)();` but in this case compiler return me the error "`pointer to member type 'void (B::)()' incompatible with object type 'A'`"

I have tried to search and apply the different suggestion found in internet but  I could not solve the problem.
What's my mistakes?

Comment: I suggest you stop using function pointers, and instead use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Together with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) it will make your code easier and more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but I'm developing the code for embedded and in my case I can't use std::function for a problem about resources optimization.

Comment: Even if you got the syntax right, you can't call the member function `A::foo` using an instance of `B`, they are unrelated classes.

Comment: Ok thank you @Mat. If I delete `B::` and `A::` in function pointers declarations the problem 2) resolved but the 1) persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member function pointers syntax is not trivial, but you have a major understanding problem here: it is *something* that point to a method of a given class. That means that:

1. you load it with a reference to a *class* and not to a (possibly polymorphic) object
2. you call it on an object of its class

First is simple, you must use this in your main:

```
instA.fnc2 = &B::fnc1;
instB.fnc2 = &baseA::fnc1; // and not A::fnc1 since fnc1 is only declared in baseA
```

For the second point, you will need a `B` object (or ref. or pointer) in `A` and a `A` object (or ref. or pointer) in `B`. I will use pointers here for simplicity:

```
class A:baseA
{
    public:
        void task(void);

        void fnc1(void);
        void (B::*fnc2)(void)=NULL;

        B* b;
};

void A::task()
{
    if(this->fnc2!=NULL && b != NULL)
        (b->*fnc2)();    // note the parentheses to avoid a syntax error
}

class B
{
    public:
        void task(void);

        void fnc1(void);
        void (baseA::*fnc2)(void);

        A* a;
};

void B::task(void)
{
    if(this->fnc2!=NULL && a != NULL)
        (a->*fnc2)();
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. The `b` and `a` pointer must be initialize before using.
However it's not clear the initialization of function pointers `instA.fnc2 = &B::fnc1;` and `instB.fnc2 = &baseA::fnc1;`: `fnc1` in `A` and `B` class should be static, is it right?

Comment: @LucaG: No.  *Member function pointers* are just pointers to a method that will receive its object as a hidden parameter. That is the reason why you need to later call them on an object. You need `std::bind` function object to bind the method and (some of) its arguments. In that sense, the object is the first argument for a method.